# Perl regexp how to escape only some chars

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, special-characters

I have a string `$regexp_as_string`

Now I want to "convert" it into an regex / use it as regexp

```
if ($text_to_search =~ $regexp_as_string)
{
...
}
```

Now there are characters like "." and I want to automaticly escape them - \Q and \E should do that

```
 if ($text_to_search =~ /\Q$regexp_as_string\E/)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Is there a way to specify a list of characters that should be auto escaped? Because at the moment that way auto escapes for example "|" , but I want to keep that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can prepare the string using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), then remove backslashes selectively. E.g.:

```
my $str = quotemeta('foo${}|'); 
$str =~ s/\\(?=[|])//g; 
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
foo\$\{\}|
```

Add any characters you want not escaped to the character class in the substitution, e.g. `[|?()]`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of passing a string joined by | for alternations, get the list of alternations and build them up into a string (or even split them by | if that is guaranteed to never appear)?  Something like:

```
my @alternations = array_returning_function();
# my @alternations = split(/\|/, string_returning_function());
my $regexp_as_string = join('|', map(quotemeta, @alternations));
```

or use [Data::Munge](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Munge/lib/Data/Munge.pm#list2re)'s list2re function:

```
use Data::Munge;
my @alternations = array_returning_function();
# my @alternations = split(/\|/, string_returning_function());
my $regexp_as_string = Data::Munge::list2re( @alternations );
```

Answer (score 0):

using TLP's example string

```
my $str='foo${}|';
$str =~ s/([\.\{\}\$])/\\$1/g;
print $str;
```

This will ONLY add a backslash to characters that are in the square brackets "character class"

Note that I've put a blackslash in front of the characters in the square brackets.  This isn't always necessary for all characters in this context but it's easier to just add a backslash and not worry about it.

Comment: Correction: It is easier to find out which characters you need to escape inside a character class (the square brackets) once and for all, and *then* not worry about it: `-]\^$` are the only meta characters you need to worry about, and even then, its mostly in how you use them. For example: `[]]` and `[abc^]` and `[a-z-]` are fine. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Using-character-classes